# How to fill CKEditor 4 using playwright?

Tags: ckeditor, e2e-testing, playwright

I am using `npx playwright codegen` to come up with code for my playwright tests. I have a CKEditor that I want to fill with some test content. When I click inside the CKEditor and write "test", the codegen generates this:

```
  // Click html
  await page.frameLocator('iframe').locator('html').click();
```

So it generates the code to click inside the CKEditor, but ignores my keyboard input. For example, with the standard HTML  elements, it generates a `.fill()` line of code to simulate my keyboard input. How can I do this for CKEditor?

I don't need the codegen to generate the .fill() logic per se, I just need a way to fill the CKEditor in general.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone gets stuck in the future, this is how you can do it, something like:

```
 await page.frameLocator('iframe').locator('html').locator('body').type("Hello");
```

https://playwright.dev/docs/input#type-characters